# Voice Recognition in Android

Tags: android

When i click on Voice Search button on Android (SDk 2.2 ) phone then an icon with a mic and text SPEAK NOW appears on phone screen. After speaking any command like "hello" a new screen with text "WORKING" and a progress bar appears. I want to know where does Voice recognition happen and where does actual Voice Analysis takes place?

Which APIs can be used to capture both events?

Answer (score 0):

The actual processing of the speech is not done on the phone, it is done on a server. For a nice and simple overview of using speech recognition you could read this article: http://www.4feets.com/2009/04/speech-recognition-in-android-sdk-15/ It's a little old but has useful information to begin with.

Comment: My Concern is i need to split the WORKING window into two screen 1) One for Voice Input completion and 2) For actual speech to text conversion and keyword matching